# How to connect C# aspx to dataset?

Tags: c#

I want a simple webpage to show dataset datas in gridview. Im creating the dataset wita winform, and I want the webpage to automatically update the gridview every 5 seconds.

Comment: To auto update, see the Webforms Timer. To connect the Dataset .. see just about any data binding tutorial ..

Comment: Please show us your own efforts. What did you try, did you read anything on the topic, where are you getting stuck? Don't expect the stackoverflow community to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Control along with [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Control for implementing your desired behaviour.

The Microsoft Ajax **Timer** control performs postbacks at defined intervals. If you use the Timer control with an **UpdatePanel** control, you can enable partial-page updates at a defined interval. You can also use the Timer control to post the whole page.

For more information on Microsoft Ajax, refer:

**[Microsoft Ajax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341002%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**